# python gui tree walk

Tags: python, tree, tkinter

I am trying to figure out how to walk a tree and then display the output in a window that a user can navigate through much like that on the left hand side of my computer. Eventually I plan to have a fully browsable window just like you have on the right hand side. Here is what I have so far, I guess it is a mix of pseudo and actual code. This is for use on a Linux machine using python. I'm not looking for any code but mainly help as to how I can accomplish this with tkinter. Perhaps it is just me but I cannot find much help that helps me solve my problem - most just tell me how to display the directories etc. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I want this window to look like this

```
My Documents <--------starting directory
    My pictures<------subdirectory
        picture1.jpg<-inside of subdirectoy
        picture2.jpg
    1234.exe<---------random file inside of my documents
```

I want to have a small folder picture next to a directory or a subdirectory also.

```
start at root
     create window with tk
     for dirname,subdirList,filelist in os.walk(root)
     create new item(dirname)   
     for i in subdirList:         #not sure what I would have to do to only    
                                           have subdirs showing once the directory was
                                           clicked once
        append i to item 1       
    for fname in fileList:          
        append fname to item 1      
    else:                    
        item +=1
```

Comment: The question isn't really clear to me. To traverse the directory tree, use `os.walk()`. Why don't you try writing some code and then post it together with a specific question, if any?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it using the widget `ttk.Treeview`, there is a demo `dirbrowser.py` that does that.  So all I can do here is give a stripped version of it and explain how it works. First, here is the short version:

```
import os
import sys
import Tkinter
import ttk

def fill_tree(treeview, node):
    if treeview.set(node, "type") != 'directory':
        return

    path = treeview.set(node, "fullpath")
    # Delete the possibly 'dummy' node present.
    treeview.delete(*treeview.get_children(node))

    parent = treeview.parent(node)
    for p in os.listdir(path):
        p = os.path.join(path, p)
        ptype = None
        if os.path.isdir(p):
            ptype = 'directory'

        fname = os.path.split(p)[1]
        oid = treeview.insert(node, 'end', text=fname, values=[p, ptype])
        if ptype == 'directory':
            treeview.insert(oid, 0, text='dummy')

def update_tree(event):
    treeview = event.widget
    fill_tree(treeview, treeview.focus())

def create_root(treeview, startpath):
    dfpath = os.path.abspath(startpath)
    node = treeview.insert('', 'end', text=dfpath,
            values=[dfpath, "directory"], open=True)
    fill_tree(treeview, node)


root = Tkinter.Tk()

treeview = ttk.Treeview(columns=("fullpath", "type"), displaycolumns='')
treeview.pack(fill='both', expand=True)
create_root(treeview, sys.argv[1])
treeview.bind('<<TreeviewOpen>>', update_tree)

root.mainloop()
```

It starts by listing the files and directories present in the path given by `sys.argv[1]`. You don't want to use `os.walk` here as you show only the contents directly available in the given path, without going into deeper levels. The code then proceeds to show such contents, and for directories it creates a dummy children so this `Treeview` entry will be displayed as something that can be further expanded. Then, as you may notice, there is a binding to the virtual event `<<TreeviewOpen>>` which is fired whenever the user clicks an item in the `Treeview` that can be further expanded (in this case, the entries that represent directories). When the event is fired, the code ends up removing the dummy node that was created earlier and now populates the node with the contents present in the specified directory. The rest of the code is composed of details about storing additional info in the `Treeview` to make everything work.

Comment: I do not fully understand the actual need for the dummy node, why can you not just add a new item without inserting a dummy node first?

Comment: @bigl you can, and in fact the dummy node is never inserted first. It is only inserted when the item is a directory, so it has a child and thus can be expanded. If it has no children, then you can't expand it.

Comment: how can I add it to my own Tkinter window by using place() method instead of using pack().

Comment: I inserted in my window but how can I change the bg color of the widget.

Answer (score -2):

I think tkinter would be a bad choice for this. Other libraries like wxPython, PyQt or GTK does have GUI components which will help you achieve this with minimum effort.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend wxPython/wxPhoenix because it is out-dated and far behind its parent wxWidgets which itself isn't quite fresh. And wxPython has only one active developer.